# Script para pegar dados de página em Php ou python

Tags: php, python, javascript-eventos

Quero implementar um script que acesse a página das impressoras aqui do meu trabalho e pegue os dados como por exemplo, numero de impressões, nomes dos usuários, basicamente quero criar um sistema de controle.

Por onde começo, queria fazer em php, mas sei que python deve ser mt mais fácil e deve ter bibliotecas prontas pra isso.

Tem uma página que consegui capturar o javascript e refazendo eu chego na página onde quero capturar os dados.

Já em outro site, eu não consigo visualizar o evento quando clico no menu, como eu posso ver isso ?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Como é novo aqui, recomendo fortemente que comece fazendo o [tour] para entender ao menos o básico do funcionamento do site. Leia também o guia de [ask]. Da maneira que está, sua pergunta está demasiadamente ampla, podendo ser fechada em muito breve.

Comment: Perfeito, vou refazer a pergunta.

Comment: O que você quer fazer é *web scraping*. Sugiro pesquisar por bibliotecas de web scrapting para PHP no packagist, por exemplo. Outra alternativa é ler o conteúdo HTML com curl e manipulá-lo via DOM. O php tem extensões para isso também.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o cURL (pesquise para saber mais opções):

Primeiramente veja se há o cURL está habilitado:

A opção php info deverá mostrar o

```
<?php info()
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sounoob.com.br/labs/pagseguro-test-
curl');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); ?>
```

Com isso você consegue uma string com o resultado da página.
Dessa forma, o php permite você **manipular o DOM da página** e extrair os dados como desejar. 
Você também poderia fazer um script usando Ajax para extrair os dados das páginas que deseja, caso não tenha alguma configuração que bloqueie esse acesso.